# selecting 4 non-consecutive books from 10 books.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> I have a set a $10$ book kept in a line and I want to find out how many ways $4$ books can be chosen from that if I don't choose consecutive books to be taken out.

I felt this is similar to forming 4 letter word not chosen consecutively from a 10 letter word. So the answer will be $10\times 8\times 6\times 4 = 1920$ ways. The possibility of first letter will be 10 and we omit the next letter so the possibility of second alphabet will be 8 and similarly it goes on. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that this is very much too large. There are only $\binom{10}{4}=210$ ways to choose $4$ books, and intuition suggests most of these choices will involve at least two consecutive books.

Comment: just started permutations and combinations.... what is this (10 4) = 210. is  is fact(10)/fact(4) ?

Comment: Maybe you call it $C(10,4)$ or $C^{10}_4$ or something related. It is the number of ways to **choose** $4$ objects from $10$. It is equal to $\frac{10!}{4!6!}$. Maybe google binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down $6$ stars, to represent in the abstract books not taken. 
$$\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast$$
These determine $7$ gaps, of which $5$ are interstar gaps, and the other two endgaps.

From these gaps, $4$ were selected for book removal. This can be done in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways.

Answer (score 3):

The same as the number of ways $4$ books can be **inserted** in gaps between the other six.

$\uparrow B \uparrow B \uparrow B \uparrow B \uparrow B \uparrow B \uparrow\;\; viz\;\; \dbinom74$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Find the number of ways you can select $4$ *consecutive* books, $6$ ways is possible.

Comment: The problem asks to find all the ways no two of the four selected books are adjacent.  You would also need to eliminate the possibility that two or three of the books are consecutive.  Also, there are $7$ ways that four consecutive books can be selected (choose the position of the first book).

Answer (score 0):

This is small enough that you can draw it out using placeholders such as this:

$1$ _ $3$ _ $5$ _ $7$..$10$ ($4$ choices)
$1$ _ $3$ _ _ $6$ _ $8$..$10$ ($3$ choices)
$1$ _ $3$ _ _ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
$1$ _ $3$ _ _ _ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)
$1$ _ _ $4$ _ $6$ _ $8$..$10$ ($3$ choices)
$1$ _ _ $4$ _ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
$1$ _ _ $4$ _ _ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)
$1$ _ _ _ $5$ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
$1$ _ _ _ $5$ _ _ $8$ _ $10$ ($1$ choices)
$1$ _ _ _ _ $6$ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)

_ $2$ _ $4$ _ $6$ _ $8$..$10$ ($3$ choices)
_ $2$ _ $4$ _ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
_ $2$ _ $4$ _ _ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)
_ $2$ _ _ $5$ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
_ $2$ _ _ $5$ _ _ $8$ _ $10$ (only $1$ choice)
_ $2$ _ _ _ $6$ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)

_ _ $3$ _ $5$ _ $7$ _ $9$..$10$ ($2$ choices)
_ _ $3$ _ $5$ _ _ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)
_ _ $3$ _ _ $6$ _ $8$ _ $10$ (only $1$ choice)

The last will be:

_ _ _ $4$ _ $6$ _ $8$ _ $10$       (only $1$ choice)

So $35$ ways possible.

Comment: are we not having formula to find it out ?

Comment: You asked for a specific case of choosing $4$ nonadjacent books in a line of $10$ so my point is when the numbers are small like that, enumeration is possible and practical.   It also helps with visualization of the actual arrangements which is less abstract than a formula.  Both methods complement and confirm each other.